# What is the difference between these two lines?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
struct node *tempNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

//and

struct node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: `(struct node*)` silences compiler errors as malloc returns a void pointer.

Comment: @Ultimater In C there won't be any warning. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: The first is considered bad practce in C; you haven't needed to explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` since the C90 standard, and under that standard doing so could suppress a useful diagnostic. And an even better way to write it is `struct node *tempNode = malloc( sizeof *tempNode );`.

Comment: The question title here should be reformulated as *Do I cast the result of malloc*, shouldn't it? But then it is apparent that it is a duplicate and should be closed as such, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node *tempNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

you're dynamically allocating space to a node pointer tempNode and typecasting it to be a struct node* type. (pointer to structure)

```
struct node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The same as above, except without the explicit typecast (struct node*)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Since `malloc` returns type `void *`, it can be assigned to a variable of any pointer type without casting. As John Bode mentioned, casting the result of `malloc` is considered bad practice because it may mask the compiler error that would result from having some other definition of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are casting it correctly there's no difference between the two.

But the cast is generally frowned upon in C since a `void*` can be implicitly converted into any other (data) pointer type.

Also see this C FAQ entry: [What's wrong with casting malloc's return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

A *third* one is there:

```
struct node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof *tempNode);
```

which is better since it makes for less changes in case the type is changed.

Comment: Isn't the first sentence contradicting the said in the link?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I included the link *precisely* for all the other relevant points. If you are talking about "forgot to include.." it's not a valid C program (implicit int is no longer allowed). Any decent compiler would issue a warning for that anyway. I don't see the full code from OP. So, I assume OP did include it. For all I know, there might have be `#define malloc NULL` if you are down to that level of nit-picking.

Comment: Assuming the first commenter to be a downvoter is a *Post hoc ergo propter hoc*. And it is not a nit-picking. Casting the result of `malloc` is a well known "no-no".

Comment: @EugeneSh. It *is*. (despite what I said in the answer an linking it to C FAQ which explains the same). Should I edit to change "frowned upon" to "no-no"?

Comment: My first comment was relating to the first sentence of your answer, which can be interpreted as a summary of the rest. You can leave this answer as is, it's up to you, and I promise I won't downvote it. But as you can see there are people who will.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You might as well pick just the "no difference" alone. Poeple are free to downvote as they please with or without a reason, I suppose. And the anonymous downvoter probably didn't bother to read anything else in the answer (or may be just read the "no" in the first sentence). Anyways, I am done here.

Answer (score -1):

With the call to `malloc`, memory is allocated that has the size of the `struct node` in bytes. It returns a `void*` to the allocated memory.

Now the thing is: both of your lines do exactly the same, but the second line will lead to a warning when compiled with a C++ compiler.

C allows implicit conversion of a `void*` to a different pointer type, whereas the C++ compiler will - at least - warn you, or give you an error.

Comment: This is not a C++ question, or java, C#, B*f etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane so what's your point? In C there is obviously no difference, but it is very likely that the questioner want's to know about this, C++ is far more related to C than anything else.

Comment: I am sorry but C++ is not on the table, not matter how "related" you think it is. In C if you think there is "obviously no difference" then you have not read the [link already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). I was tempted to DV but gave you the opportunity to retract the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I read that; it still makes absolutely no difference to functioning of the code if you cast or not.

Comment: No, but it makes a difference to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and your lack of knowledge, and no, it *doesn't* make a difference to the C compiler.

Comment: I am saying your answer is off topic - would have been better as a comment, if at all.